# Pass a variable between controller and use ng-repeat on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, smartystreets

Some of my wording may be off especially regarding angular/js terminology (controller, service, factory, etc), but hopefully it is still understandable. Also, this question has multiple parts, which made it difficult to ask in one line.

I have 3 files: *newRegistration.html, Registration.js,* and *addressVerification.js*.

In *newRegistration.html*, there is a form where the user inputs his/her email, phone, mailing address, and other things and then clicks "next". Upon clicking next, *Registration.js* (a controller?) is triggered (?).

**newRegistration.html**

In the following snippet is the `ng-repeat` that I'd like to update with new data from *addressVerification.js*.

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="CHOOSE THE CORRECT ADDRESS">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="for item in [not sure what to put here because of two js files]">

        </li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

**Registration.js**

The controller for the template that contains the `ng-repeat` mentioned above.

The top line looks like this:

```
angular.module('appname')
    .controller('RegistrationCtrl', function ($scope, $http, cacheStore, countryStates, birthYear, $anchorScroll, errorMessages, addressVerification, UtilsFactory)
```

And this is a line that may be relevant:

```
addressVerification.verify(user).then(function (userObj)
```

**addressVerification.js**

Uses the Smartystreets API to correct/suggest the mailing address.

I can't figure out how to pass variables from this module to Registration.js (where the scope variable [?] is) in order to populate the `ng-repeat` in *newRegistration.html*.

```
angular.module('appname').factory('addressVerification', function($q, userIdentity, $http,  smartyToken) {
    "use strict";

    return {
    verify: function(obj) {
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
        street2QS = "";

    if (obj.address2 || obj.address2 !== "") {
        street2QS = "&street2=" + encodeURIComponent(obj.address2);
    }

$http.jsonp("https://api.smartystreets.com/street-address?street=" + encodeURIComponent(obj.address1)
    + street2QS
    + "&city=" + encodeURIComponent(obj.city)
+ "&state=" + encodeURIComponent(obj.state)
+ "&zipcode=" + encodeURIComponent(obj.zip)
+ "&source=website&auth-token="+ smartyToken.get() + "&candidates=5&callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
.success(function (response) {
    var metaData,
    components;

        if (response && response.length === 1) {
        metaData = response[0].metadata || {};
        components = response[0].components || {};

            angular.extend(obj, {
        "address1": [
            components.primary_number,
        components.street_name,
        components.street_suffix
                    ].join(" "),
        "address2": [
        components.secondary_designator,
        components.secondary_number
        ].join(" "),
        "city": components.city_name,
        "county_name": metaData.county_name,
        "county_fips": metaData.county_fips,
        "state": components.state_abbreviation,
        "latitude": metaData.latitude,
        "longitude": metaData.longitude,
        "plus4_code": components.plus4_code,
        "zip": components.zipcode
        });
        deferred.resolve(obj);
        } else {
            deferred.reject(false);
        }
        }).error( function() {
            deferred.reject(false);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
    };
});
```

I'm pretty clueless right now. I think I've given all of the necessary details. I wish I knew where to start. I read all about deferred objects, ng-repeat, and controllers, but it's confusing me.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're injecting addressVerification into RegistrationCtrl. The value of addressVerification that is injected into the RegistrationCtrl is the value returned by executing the function you're defining here:

```
angular.module('appname')
.factory('addressVerification', function($q, userIdentity, $http, smartyToken)
```

Therefore you can access the stuff that's happening inside of the addressVerification.js file in the RegistrationCtrl.js file by adding methods to whatever it is you're returning in that function.

Once you have your data in RegistrationCtrl, you can access it from the view by appending data to the scope inside of RegistrationCtrl. Example:

This would go in RegistrationCtrl.js:

```
$scope.someItems = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

This would go in the view:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in someItems">{{item}}</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have some confusion because the entire file (addressVerification.js) is wrapped in a return statement, and then there is a "return deferred.promise" statement at the end too. Does this sound familiar?

Comment: also, what do you mean adding methods to what I'm returning?

Comment: Can you post what addressVerification.js looks like? If it's returning an object (ie: return { ... }) then you can add methods to it and access those methods inside of your controller.

Comment: edited the questions to include the entire addressVerification.js

Comment: So addressVerification is returning a JavaScript object with a verify property. You can add additional properties or refactor the object to use additional methods if you want to execute the code from inside the controller.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I have implemented this is by exposing methods of a factory that allow the controllers (and the controller's view(s)) that depend on it to store values within the same factory.

For example, in the following code, the `setCurrent` method of the `customers` factory stores a value, `current` in the factory. Because factories are singletons,  will persist in the application. Even after the user's click on the `<a>` (in the following example) and they are taken to `href="/"`, the value that was stored in `customers.current` will be accessible to the "/" route's controller if the same factory is a dependency for both controllers.

**Template**

```
<ul>
    <li>{{customers.current.name}}</li>
    <li 
        ng-repeat="customer in customers.all"
        >
        <a 
            class="action name"
            ng-click="customers.setCurrent(customer)"
            href="/"
            >
            {{customer.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
angular
.module('CtrlCustomerList', [
    'CollectionCustomers',
])
.controller('CtrlCustomerList', function($scope, CollectionCustomers) {
    $scope.customers = CollectionCustomers;
});
```

**Factory**

```
angular
.module('CollectionCustomers', [
])
.factory("CollectionCustomers", function(Restangular, ModelCustomer, $location) {
    return {
        all     : [],
        current : null,
        setCurrent : function() {
            // Affect this.current
        }
    }
});
```